# Modificar variable en un PHP Session

Tags: php, html

Tengo esto en un archivo PHP

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php $inscripcioncerrada = "inscripcioncerrada.php" ?>
<?php $inscripcionabierta = "inscripcionabierta.php" ?>    
<?php $_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $inscripcioncerrada ?>
```

en las paginas a las que hago referencia a `$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion']` tengo nada mas empezar un include tal que `<?php include("periodoinscripcion.php"); ?>` que es como se llama el archivo.

Hasta ahí todo correcto.

Bien, ahora lo que quiero (no se si es posible hacerlo) es hacer un script para modificar esa variable `$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion']` en el archivo PHP para que asi cuando el resto de paginas hagan referencia a ella salga el nuevo valor.

Es decir, si por ejemplo la inscripcion esta cerrada, que llamando a un script me la cambie a abierta (`$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $inscripcionabierta`) en el PHP. Asi todas las paginas que la incluyen cambian el valor.

Como hacerlo?

Comment: Deberías de ser un poco más explícito.

Comment: Creo que soy bastante explicito. Dime que tienes dudas y aclaro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS**

```
function llamadaAjax() {

            var nuevoEstado = 'minuevaurl.php', //Valor a asignar a la $_SESSION
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('POST', 'miphp.php'); //El PHP con el código que cambia la SESSION
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.responseText !== nuevoEstado) {
                    alert("Cambiado!");

                }
                else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                    alert('Error ' + xhr.status);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(encodeURI('estado=' + nuevoEstado)); //Envíamos variable 
}
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["estado"])) { //Nos aseguramos de que no llegue vacía
    $_SESSION["miVarDeSesion"] = $_REQUEST["estado"]; 
}
```